# Class diagram operation

Tags: implementation, uml, class-diagram, operation

Modeling class diagram requires set of classes associated with each others, each class has a set of attributes and operations.

My question is:
how and where should i model implementations (bodies) for those operations?

Asking because i have confusion in understanding the application of concepts `class`, `interface`, `abstract class`

Answer (score 3):

I agree that Interface and Abstract are set of "empty" (i.e. without code) Operation. 
It does not really exist a place for model implementation I mean each tool RSx, Rhapsody, Modelio, etc has its own strategy. It could be model as a UML Comment, an OpaqueBehavior, or an Activity owned by the Operation.
UML does not define where and how the code (Operation bodies) should be.

I add a screenshot of Java code modelling using Modelio. As you see a specific UML Comment , named Code is created under the UML operation and the body of this comment are the code of the method [image: Java Hello Word]

Comment: thank you @Red Beard
if we assume that we are using Modelio as a modelling environment for showing the implementation of an operation of one class (away from interface and abstract class)
could you please clarify how can do this by simple example?

Comment: I edited my previous response in order to add a screenshot. For doing it, I just reversed a piece of Java code

Comment: thank you @Red Bread very much
i create class with single operation and then associate note element to operation
i also added the java designer module but i didn't know how to continue 
could you please provide the steps for doing this ?

Comment: @Andrew so the steps are : 1) create a project 2) deploy javadesigner 3) create a class (UML) 4) specify in the Java tab that the created class is a Java element 5) Create an operation under the class 6) Add to the Operation a Java Code Note. You should find more details here http://forge.modelio.org/projects/javadesigner-documentation/wiki or ask for it here http://www.modelio.org/forum/index.html

Answer (score 0):

When representing a class in UML, the box will contain three sections.
First section is the name of the class
Second section is the names of the class variables.
Third section is the names of the class methods (with the types of the parameters and the return value).

The difference between a class (which has an implementation) and an Interface (which is basically a list of empty methods without an implementation) is that the interface will have a dedicated tag above its name.

When a class uses an interface, it "promises" to implement all the functions described in said interface.

To summarize :
- Abstract class : can contain variables, abstract methods (an "empty" method without implementation) and regular methods. An abstract class may not be instantiated.

- Interface : a set of "empty" methods
- Class : a class can extend one (and ONLY one) Abstract class, in which case it needs to implement the abstract methods. A class can also implement several interfaces (likewise, the class must implement the methods defined in the interfaces).